# Determine game was launched from Google Play Games App

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-play-games

We are developing an Android game. One way to launch our game is through the "Google Play Games" app (the games catalog) that can be downloaded from [Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.play.games&hl=en).

When launching the game from the catalog (by selecting its page and hitting "Play"), the game starts, but there are no extras or any further data placed in the intent.

There is no way i can think of that can help me determine that the game was launched from the "Play Games" app.

Is there any way to determine this information? How can we know that we were launched from there ?

Comment: 4 years down the line, did you ever figure out how to do it?

Comment: not really, and i am not even sure why we needed that info.
I suppose that there are ways to get this information, but they are not bullet proof. For example - you can check the "referrer" for the installation, but i am not sure that you will get it if you install the game from the store, but then launch it from the launcher icon or something like that (you can check it yourself).